# removing rows on conditions from nested data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am having an interesting issue with some data. I am trying to keep only rows that have source 'four' , for the same day,inside a nested df.
This is an attached sample of the mock transformation. My challenge that this needs to happen at the nested dataset level and keep the nested df.

Data example:

```
date    source
30/12/2013  0
30/12/2013  2
30/12/2013  3
30/12/2013  7
29/12/2013  four
29/12/2013  1
29/12/2013  6
```

Transformation example:

```
date    source
30/12/2013  0
30/12/2013  2
30/12/2013  3
30/12/2013  7
29/12/2013  four
```

Code example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


fl <- nycflights13::weather %>%   mutate(date = make_date(year, month, day)) %>% 
  mutate(source = sample(0:7, n(), replace = TRUE))   %>%  mutate(source = replace(source, source == 4, 'four'))
fl<- sample_frac(fl, 0.3)
fl<- fl %>% group_by(origin) %>% nest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to go over each data and select rows with `source == 'four'` if `'four'` value is present in the day or select all the rows otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)
fl %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, ~.x %>% 
                                    group_by(day) %>% 
                                    filter(if(any(source == 'four'))
                                     source == 'four' else TRUE)))
```